# Omitted preposition or lack of comma?

Tags: prepositions

In the given example:

> If we were to use the definite article, there would have to be **in the context** a given good thing to which we refer, something well enough determined so that it can be identified.

Shouldn't it be *in the context **of*** (with a preposition) or *in the context,* (with a comma)?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's just a rearrangement of

> If we were to use the definite article, there would have to be a given good thing to which we refer **in the context**, something well enough determined so that it can be identified.

The word *particular* might be better than the word *given* in that sentence.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's is more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's the kind of sentence like "there's a cup on the table": There would have to be / a given good thing / in the context. The parts saying *what* and *where* are in a different order, probably to adjoin the clause "to which we refer" smoothly and unambiguously.

Comment: thanks, I was fooled by my native language, where I expected comma for it to make sense in the way you described.